# Add space between td's when grabbing .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add space between td's when using a `.text()`?

I was not able to find anything through google, only how to trim space.

My line looks like this

```
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    var something= $(rows[i]).text(); 
}
```

It is currently jamming everything together like

```
"OneTwoThreeFour"
```

I would like it to be

"One Two Three Four"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161840/discussion-on-question-by-zazvorniki-add-space-between-tds-when-grabbing-text).

Answer (score 4):

How about pushing the text of the elements into an array and then using join()?

```
var textArray = [];

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    textArray.push($(rows[i]).text()); 
}

var result = textArray.join(' ');
```

Comment: I can't have an array of items unfortunately. Or else I would have an array within an array within an object

Comment: @zazvorniki This doesn't create an array within an array within an object, where are you getting that from?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt This snippet does not. But I am trying avoid another array because in my code I have multiple arrays within an object.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to solve the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

```
 var str = '';

 for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
     str += $(rows[i]).text() + " ";
 }

 str = str.trim(); // For remove last space
```

Comment: This just adds a space to the end of the values. Like "OneTwoThreeFour ". I need to add a space between each value. "One Two Three Four"

Comment: It's just simple tr's "<tr>One</tr>
<tr>Two</tr>
<tr>Three</tr>
<tr>Four</tr>"

Comment: Hanif, it adds a space between each value. The for loop executes over the rows and adds a space after *each* value, not just the last one.

Comment: What does console.log(rows) display? @zazvorniki

Comment: @TiagoCoelho - I just assuming that in 'rows' is the place from where we taking text by .text() function. Question owner even did not provided any reference about this.